# Scrollbar of a percentage div

Tags: css, html, height, scrollbar, percentage

I've got two divs within a main div, and one of the div's is supposed to fill the the remaining height within the div and a scrollbar should be used to show excess content. When I have the div set with a percentage height, the scrollbar does not work and all of the content is shown. The main div is meant to fill the size of the page. If I set the div to a specific pixel height this works, however this is not what is wanted.

```
html, body {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
}

#main {
    float: right;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 11%;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width:auto;
    max-height: auto
}

#half {
    max-width: 40%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 40%;
    overflow-y: scroll
}

#second {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10%
}
```

Comment: Have you got a JsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajs122/qWXN2/. I uploaded all of the code for the page